# Does there exist a function to tell if the current tileLayer is **already** loaded?

Tags: leaflet

I want to programmatically `flyTo` to a new location, then once arriving at the new location **and** the tiles in the new location are loaded, I would like to do the next step.

Using the `load` event does not work if the new location is very close to the origin, since they are already loaded, so no new `load` event would be fired. Nevertheless, the code still needs to handle whether the visible tiles are loaded, since it is possible that the new location is quite far from the origin.

How do I tell if the current tile layer is **already** loaded? Something like `map.whenReady`, which is fired immediately if the map is **already** ready, unlike `tileLayer.on("load")`, which won't be fired if the tile layer is already loaded.

Sample code that doesn't work:

```
map.on("moveend zoomend", function(){
    baseLayer.on("load", function(){
        // do something
    });
});
map.flyTo(latlng);
```

If the tile layer is already loaded, the "load" event won't fire, and `do something` won't be executed.

What I would like to have:

```
map.on("moveend zoomend", function(){
    baseLayer.whenLoaded(function(){
        // do something
    });
});
map.flyTo(latlng);
```

How to achieve this in Leaflet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution, but I think you could solve your problem using `TileLayer` [`isLoading()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#tilelayer-isloading) method that returns `true` if any tile in the grid layer has not finished loading.

```
map.on("moveend zoomend", function(){

    baseLayer.on("load", function(){
        doSomething("load: YES");
    });

    if (!baseLayer.isLoading()) doSomething("load: NO");

});

function doSomething(info) {
    alert("do something - " + info);
}
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. So if it returns false, it means it has finished loading (since we assume that it would have started loading immediately if any tile is not loaded)? In your example, am I right to say that the only race condition that can occur is when the map is not fully loaded by the time we set the handler on "load", but then it finishes loading just before the isLoading condition is checked?

Comment: I have modified code to use handler only when necessary; in my test project seems to work better.

Comment: The updated one seems to have a very very small chance of not firing the event, right? When the map is still loading at the `if` line, but finished loading before `baseLayer.on`.

Comment: sorry, I did some tests but not too many: rollbacked to previous code.

Comment: Ah, sure. We need to take a trade-off anyway. Either not firing or firing twice. I opt to fire twice.

Answer (score 2):

As already [answered](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7481#issuecomment-799564615) on github, it's easy to implement `whenReady` in your own code using Leaflet extension methods, like this:

```js
L.GridLayer.include({
    whenReady: function (callback, context) {
        if (!this._loading) {
            callback.call(context || this, {target: this});
        } else {
            this.on('load', callback, context);
        }
        return this;
    },
});
```

Comment: Ah ok, so this is to implement my own `whenReady` function using internal tools, and also more generic than the other answer. Thanks for the answer! Is the possibility of race condition a concern here? (For example, when the map is not loaded when checking `this._loading` but is loaded before `this.on('load')` is registered)

Comment: I do not expect such condition because tilelayer begins to load only when map 'is ready' (i.e. view params are set).

Comment: Ah, but this is supposed to be used on an action that is done during user's interactions (so the map is already "ready" I suppose). Does that still applies?

Comment: I mean, since the map is already ready, then tilelayer can begin loading after `!this._loading` check, right?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what do you want to ask. Is there something unclear with proposed code sample?

Comment: The code sample is clear. My question is more about race condition. Is it possible that the callback is not called? If so, how likely?

Comment: The callback must be called after all tiles loaded. Feel free to report if you find any condition preventing this.